# RefreshAll in excel file with xlwings

Tags: python, excel, refresh, xlwings

I wanted to **RefreshAll** database connections in a number of excel files but i didn't want to run an Excel macro from within python. I just wanted one line of xlwings code.

I looked everywhere on SO, github, other forums and blogs but couldn't find it.

My answer is below for others who'll have the same issue in the future.

Answer (score 4):

To **RefreshAll** connections in one excel file you only need: `wbk.api.RefreshAll()`

```
import xlwings as xw
# open Excel app in the background
app_excel = xw.App(visible = False)

wbk = xw.Book( 'D:\stuff\file.xlsx' )
wbk.api.RefreshAll()

# two options to save
wbk.save( 'D:\stuff\file.xlsx' ) # this will overwrite the file
wbk.save( 'D:\stuff\name1.xlsx' ) # this will save the file with a name

# kill Excel process
app_excel.kill()
del app_excel
```

Comment: it dosn't work with MacOSX. 
I've tried wb.api.refreshall() nothing.
If I try wb.api.refresh() I get a parameter error.