# How to refresh only certain formulas in Excel using Xlwings?

Tags: python, excel, refresh, xlwings

For Xlwings I've read up how to refresh an entire workbook([RefreshAll in excel file with xlwings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53871709/refreshall-in-excel-file-with-xlwings)) but what if I want to exclude some formulas? I have some formulas with values that I need to use but they can't be refreshed since they'll make a DIV/0 issue. The values will be part of other formula calculations though.

What I'm looking to do is:

- Update data in certain cells
- Refresh formulas excluding a subset
- Take data from formulas results that build on the excluded subset's values

Comment: You can use **.api.Calculate()** to re-calc just those cells in a \<range\>, E.g.  **wb.sheets('Sheet1').range('A1:A10').api.Calculate()** would update the formula values in cells A1 to A10 only (with the expectation that the wb is set to manual calculation).